# PHP Won't send a stack trace or error details with a 500 server error

Tags: php, centos7

I've taken over an old project and I noticed that the 500 responses sent to the browser contain no information. Since I'm working on this locally, I'd like to see what is going on.

I tried making my own new file with the follwing

```
<?php
throw new Exception("bleh");
echo "test";

?>
```

That does return 500, but again it is an empty response. This is my php.conf. With the exception of the last two lines, it is stock from the yum install on Cent OS 7

```
#
# Cause the PHP interpreter to handle files with a .php extension.
#
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

#
# Allow php to handle Multiviews
#
AddType text/html .php

#
# Add index.php to the list of files that will be served as directory
# indexes.
#
DirectoryIndex index.php

#
# Uncomment the following lines to allow PHP to pretty-print .phps
# files as PHP source code:
#
#<FilesMatch \.phps$>
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
#</FilesMatch>

#
# Apache specific PHP configuration options
# those can be override in each configured vhost
#
php_value session.save_handler "files"
php_value session.save_path    "/var/lib/php/session"

# my adds
php_value error_reporting "ALL"
```

The last few lines of tailing /var/log/httpd/error_log are

```
[Sat Jun 25 17:41:03.269154 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2804] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sat Jun 25 17:41:03.269537 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2804] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Jun 25 17:41:03.280894 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2804] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 25 17:41:03.280915 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2804] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Thanks for any help, I've been staring at this and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Check the error logs on the server.

Comment: I tailed the last few lines of /var/log/httpd/error_log and added it to the initial post for better formatting

Comment: not really an answer, but have a look [whoops](https://github.com/filp/whoops), it will make debugging so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this not by modifying the php.conf as I was above, but by modifying `/etc/php.ini` which had the setting `display_errors` set to off. By setting it to `On` errors appeared in the browser as I wanted.

Comment: you can change that at runtime, also, by using `ini_set()` function (e.g. in some bootstrap/config file, even better to make it depend on some "debug mode" so it can be easily switched off in production)

Comment: Yeah I've done that in other projects, but this is a legacy app that is pretty scattered. I was worried that it might be set different in different places and wanted something more global. I should still do a global search for ini_set() just to see what I"m up against, now that you mention it.